# Website for technical school - cms or framework?

Tags: web, content-management-system

I'm really curious if I should try to code this myself or if there are any cms that can do this? It's a website for the school I'm working at. On the front end, there is basic stuff like displaying news on the front page, registration, etc. But what unique features I'm looking for are

- showing course outline. Registered users can apply for classes.
- All classes are showed, but not all can be applied since they'll have prerequisites
- The user's account would keep track of the classes the user had applied. When they complete a class, we update their status manually. No need automatic here. Classes that require prerequisites would open up for them accordingly
- Not required but really nice to have is a discussion forum. Where users will only have access to the classes they applied for.

Is there any CMS that could do this? I'm using Contao for my current website with Xenforo for the forum and keeping everything updated manually is getting really confusing as the school is growing quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should stick with contao (because your familiar with) and look if you use plugins, maybe you can ask the community which plugins are good for your case.

If you can't find a good plugin or you can't get all features to work with plugins you can write your own plugin.

First advantage of using a cms for that you can concentrate on features that are needed for the school, don't have to write the system to blog, make sites, ...

second advantage is you have a community if you have problems with contao/cms or develeoping the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have some special functional requirements and I don't think that there are ready-to-use systems or extensions for CMS with your needs.

So you will need to develop your own system or you have the possibility to write an extension for a CMS. When you have experience with the CMS Contao you can write modules for it (with a little bit of inital skill training). I think this would be the best solution for your problem.

[A tutorial for a simple contao module](http://blog.qzminski.com/2010/09/create-a-custom-contao-module-part-one/)

Answer (score 0):

Not at all!
First: you need basic functionality - which every cms has (registration/login, show news/articles/calendars and more)
Second: you have individual functions (courses/functions,..), no cms has such default functionality.

Solution: you can program your own extension for your cms or you can search around for already existing extensions which has similar functionality and you can adapt for your requirements.

alternative solution: you can handle course/class registration with the build in user-right-controll system. there will be no need to develop your own extension.

I'm knowing contao and joomla (but there is also wordpress, drupal,...).
For me the way Contao works is great and the way extensions are programmed is much familiar to me than the joomla way.

i will suggest you to have a look to contao!